# How to make debug apk with gradlew?

Tags: build, cmd, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I have been trying to make a debug apk with gradlew but whatever I seem to do it keeps failing the build. Here is my cmd log if  it helps:

```
C:\Users\svond_000\Downloads\dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\dalviksdk\samples\HelloWorld\javafx>gradlew.bat assembledebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'HelloWorld'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadta.xml
 Required by:
     :HelloWorld:unspecified > me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:2.4.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.394 secs
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The fils is present there: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/#maven-metadata.xml. Have You specified `jcenter()` in repositories block in `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0):

> Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.

Find and change `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.` to `Ccom.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+` at your project.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "0.8" in C:\Users\svond_000.gradle. It should be present in an ivy.xml file. Make sure the line is "com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+" and save. I also had to install the 21.1.1 build tools using the android sdk manager.